# How to make periodic events in a C# class?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, timer

I want to make a class change one of its properties every second. The change is supposed to happen on class-level and not in the main thread, how would I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use System.Threading.Timer:

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer;

public YourClass()
{
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(UpdateProperty, null, 1000, 1000);
}

private void UpdateProperty(object state)
{
    lock(this)
    {
        // Update property here.
    }
}
```

Remember to lock the instance while reading the property because the UpdateProperty is called in a different thread (a ThreadPool thread)

Answer (score 3):

It’s very simple in .net 6 now.

```
using System;
using System. Threading;
using PeriodicTimer timer = new (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (1));|
 while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync ())
{
    //implement your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do in on different thread, use `BackgroundWorker` and put the logic of changing property in `DoWork`.

If you want to do something repeatedly, you should just use a `loop` inside the backgroundworker `DoWork()` method instead of using `Timer` class since it seems pointless to use with `BackgroundWorker`. Here's some rough code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    int delay = 1000; // 1 second
    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        do something
        Thread.Sleep(delay);
    }
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Whenever you want to stop the property Updation calls the `CancelAsync` on worker instance like this -

```
worker.CancelAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

In a form, the easiest way is to create a timer.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Tick);
}

private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ ... }
```

My guess would be that you can use a Timer even outside a form, since it's a Component and not a Control.